# What does the word 「たたっつけて」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

Here is the sentence that contains the word I came across.

> あとでつらあ**たたっつけて**あやまってもようしゃしねえぞ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a working-class accent of たたきつけて. I feel it is べらんめえ口調(江戸言葉). https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%9F%E6%88%B8%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89